# templated printMap not compiling

Tags: c++, stdmap

Trying to implement a printMap class, which is obviously to print the content of the maps I am using, it didn't compile complaining about the types of inputs in std::map<>::iterator. How do i get rid of that problem and get this compiled ?

```
template <class tagType, class valueType>
void printMap (const std::map<tagType, valueType>& myMap)
{
    if (myMap.size()== 0)
        return;
    if (DEBUG_PRINT) {
    std::map<tagType, valueType>::const_iterator it = myMap.begin();
    std::map<tagType, valueType>::const_iterator itEnd = myMap.end();
    std::cout << "================================================================================" << std::endl;
    for (; it != itEnd; it++)
        std::cout << (*it).first << ":" << (*it).second << std::endl;
    std::cout << "================================================================================" << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

> error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::map::const_iterator’ because ‘std::map’ is
>   a dependent scope
>        std::map::const_iterator it = myMap.begin();
>        ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can also, use following loop 
`for(__typeof(myMap.begin()) it = (myMap.begin()); it!= myMap.end(); it++)`

*declared new variable (pointer) `it` which is equals to size `myMap.begin()`, loop will increase to until `it` is different to `myMap.end()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need ‘`typename`’ before ‘`std::map::const_iterator`’ because ‘`std::map`’ is a dependent scope.

What that means is that `const_iterator` is not known until the template is instanciated, so you need to mention that it's actually a type (otherwise it is considered a variable).

In your example :

```
typename std::map<tagType, valueType>::const_iterator it = myMap.begin();
```

Comment: Did you just re-write the error message in a different format to me ? I know that. How does (and is it possible) one fix it ?

Comment: @navderm Yes I did. Because it's telling you exactly what to do : when you use a type that is inside a template class, you need to prefix it with `typename`.

Comment: I am trying to understand what your comment meant. Did you mean typename needs to be used with the line where I define ::const_iterator ? If that's so, how do i do that ?

Comment: @navderm There you go :)

Comment: aah !! I knew that ! Sorry, my bad !